# Fetch API cannot load and Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch Errors in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, fetch-api

I understand there have been updates to d3.JS and I've been racking the Internet and stack overflow for guidance on loading an external json or csv file. I've modified the function to fetch the data and still receive 2 errors:

Error 1: Fetch API cannot load 
Error 2: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

I'm not sure what is causing this. I've attempted a few different modifications from other posts with no luck. Any assistance is appreciated.

```
d3.csv('mydata.csv').then(function(data){

var canvas = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width', 700)
  .attr('height', 700)

canvas.selectAll('rect')
   .data(data)
   .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('width', function(d){
        return d.age * 10
    })
    .attr('height', 48)
    .attr('y', function(d, i){
        return i * 50
    })
    .attr('fill', 'orange')

canvas.selectAll('text')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
    .append('text')
    .attr('fill', 'blue')
    .attr('y', function(d, i){
        return i * 50 + 30
    })
    .text(function(d){
        return d.name
    })
})
```

Comment: it all depends on the version of d3 you are using. It looks like you use d3v5

Comment: yeah I'm using d3v5

Comment: is it a CORS problem?

Comment: I thought that at first, but I turned it off and on to see and no change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're using the latest version of [D3](https://d3js.org/)
Also if you're confused about CORS, try to upload your data file to [Github GIST](https://gist.github.com/) and use the raw URL to the CSV data file.
Or if your data is in a different server you can try this https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ followed by your data/csv URL.

See example using your code and gist here

```js
d3.csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/radaatyr/732f30394301fdc1384e9d109db428cb/raw/407167e7cc69036076945a9f1a02deafb5c26163/mydata.csv').then(function(data){

var canvas = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width', 700)
  .attr('height', 700)

canvas.selectAll('rect')
   .data(data)
   .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('width', function(d){
        return d.age * 10
    })
    .attr('height', 48)
    .attr('y', function(d, i){
        return i * 50
    })
    .attr('fill', 'orange')

canvas.selectAll('text')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
    .append('text')
    .attr('fill', 'blue')
    .attr('y', function(d, i){
        return i * 50 + 30
    })
    .text(function(d){
        return d.name
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```